# PHP Inserting into SQL table error with syntax

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm learning how to use PHP with MySQLi and I'm having issues correctly inserting information into a table I have set up. Here's my code:

```
 $temp_category = $_POST['category'];
    $temp_fname = $_POST['recipient-fname'];
    $temp_lname = $_POST['recipient-lname'];
    $temp_email = $_POST['recipient-email'];
    $temp_date = $_POST['award-date']; 
    $auth_userId = $_SESSION['id'];
    $auth_email = $_SESSION['email'];


    $mysqli = mysqli_connect($host, $dbUser, $dbPword, $db, $port);
    if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
    }

    $sql = 'INSERT INTO award_entry (award_category,granted_time,authorizing_user_id,authorizing_user_email,fname,lname,recipient_email),
    VALUES ("'.$temp_category.'", "'.$temp_date.'","'.$auth_userId.'", "'.$auth_email.'","'.$temp_fname.'", "'.$temp_lname.'","'.$temp_email.'")';


    if ($mysqli->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "award_entry successfully updated";
    }
    else {
         echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $mysqli->error;
    }
```

I keep getting the error You have an error "in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' VALUES ("EmployeeWeek", "2016-11-05","20", "jenisearaujo@gmail.com","Jack",' at line 1"

But I don't see what is wrong with my code.

Comment: `recipient_email),` <<< ahem.

Comment: ... *off-(cough)topic* - typo

Comment: and do use a prepared statement; you're in for an sql injection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $sql = 'INSERT INTO award_entry (award_category,granted_time,authorizing_user_id,authorizing_user_email,fname,lname,recipient_email)***,***
VALUES ("'.$temp_category.'", "'.$temp_date.'","'.$auth_userId.'", "'.$auth_email.'","'.$temp_fname.'", "'.$temp_lname.'","'.$temp_email.'")';
```

get rid of the comma after the close parenthesis right before VALUES